# How to display different menu content in different view in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Good Day!
I'm new in Ionic and I'm hoping that you can help me.
I used ionic start myApp sidemenu in creating a project.
How can I display different menu content in different user view.
For example I have 2 different user: Student and Parent, then I want to display limited menu content in parent's view:

(menu.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ionicons.css">
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">

    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
          <!-- <h2>{{userInfo.username}}</h2> -->

          <input name="student" type="checkbox" ng-model="studlist">
          <input name="parent" type="checkbox" ng-model="parentlist">
          <!-- STUDENT MENU -->
          <div ng-if="studlist">
            <a href="#/app/studhome" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-home">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/studhome" class="icon ion-clipboard">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ANNOUNCEMENTS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/events" class="icon ion-calendar">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC CALENDAR
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/viewgrades" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-android-person">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;STUDENT INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/viewgrades" class="icon ion-ios-folder">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GRADES
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/ranking" class="icon ion-stats-bars">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RANKING
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/viewschedules" class="icon ion-pin">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SCHEDULES
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/advising" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-compose">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ADVISING</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/advising" class="icon ion-chatbox-working">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ADVISING NOTIFICATION
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/academicdelinquency" class="icon ion-sad">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC DELINQUENCY
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/curriculum" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-information">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/curriculum" class="icon ion-ios-cog">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CURRICULUM
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/subjectenrolled" class="icon ion-ios-checkmark">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBJECT ENROLLED
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/history" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-book">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PDM INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/history" class="icon ion-ios-lightbulb">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HISTORY
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/officials" class="icon ion-ios-people">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SCHOOL OFFICIALS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/marilaohymn" class="icon ion-ios-musical-notes">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MARILAO HYMN
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/settings" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-android-settings">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SETTINGS</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/settings" class="icon ion-gear-b">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACCOUNT SETTINGS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="" class="icon ion-locked">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LOGOUT
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          </div>


          <!-- PARENT MENU -->
          <div ng-if="parentlist">
            <a href="#/app/studhome" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-home">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/studhome" class="icon ion-clipboard">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ANNOUNCEMENTS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/events" class="icon ion-calendar">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC CALENDAR
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/viewgrades" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-android-person">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;STUDENT INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/viewgrades" class="icon ion-ios-folder">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GRADES
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/ranking" class="icon ion-stats-bars">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RANKING
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/viewschedules" class="icon ion-pin">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SCHEDULES
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/curriculum" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-information">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACADEMIC INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/curriculum" class="icon ion-ios-cog">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CURRICULUM
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/subjectenrolled" class="icon ion-ios-checkmark">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBJECT ENROLLED
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/history" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-ios-book">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PDM INFORMATION</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/history" class="icon ion-ios-lightbulb">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HISTORY
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/officials" class="icon ion-ios-people">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SCHOOL OFFICIALS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/marilaohymn" class="icon ion-ios-musical-notes">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MARILAO HYMN
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <a href="#/app/settings" menu-close><div class="menutitle ion-android-settings">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SETTINGS</div></a>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="#/app/settings" class="icon ion-gear-b">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ACCOUNT SETTINGS
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close>
          <div class="sub">
            <a href="" class="icon ion-locked">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LOGOUT
            </a>
          </div>
          </ion-item>
          </div>


      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

(app.js)

```
    // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })


    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.loginparent', {
      url: '/loginparent',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/loginparent.html',
          controller: 'LoginParentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.loginstud', {
      url: '/loginstud',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/loginstud.html',
          controller: 'LoginStudCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.studhome', {
      url: '/studhome',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/studhome.html',
          controller: 'StudHomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.parenthome', {
      url: '/parenthome',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/parenthome.html',
          controller: 'ParentHomeCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.curriculum', {
      url: '/curriculum',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/curriculum.html',
          controller: 'CurriculumCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.subjectenrolled', {
      url: '/subjectenrolled',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/subjectenrolled.html',
          controller: 'SubjectEnrolledCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.ranking', {
      url: '/ranking',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/ranking.html',
          controller: 'RankingCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.viewgrades', {
      url: '/viewgrades',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/viewgrades.html',
          controller: 'ViewGradesCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.viewschedules', {
      url: '/viewschedules',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/viewschedules.html',
          controller: 'ViewSchedulesCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.advising', {
      url: '/advising',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/advising.html',
          controller: 'AdvisingCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.academicdelinquency', {
      url: '/academicdelinquency',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/academicdelinquency.html',
          controller: 'AcademicDelinquencyCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.events', {
      url: '/events',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
          controller: 'EventsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.officials', {
      url: '/officials',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/officials.html',
          controller: 'OfficialsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.history', {
      url: '/history',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/history.html',
          controller: 'HistoryCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.marilaohymn', {
      url: '/marilaohymn',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/marilaohymn.html',
          controller: 'MarilaoHymnCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
          controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.logout', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

;
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

(controllers.js)

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
    $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });


  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };  


  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
   // $scope.clickMe = function (){
   //  alert(0);
   // }

   // $scope.name1 = "hello";
})
.controller('LoginParentCtrl', function($scope) {

})
.controller('LoginStudCtrl', function($scope,$state,$rootScope,$http,$ionicLoading,$ionicModal) {
  $scope.studentnumber = "";
  $scope.username = "";
  $scope.password = "";

  $scope.login = function (studentnumber,username,password) {

  //$cookies.put('studentnumber',username);
//-----------LOGIN---------------------
   $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...'
    }).then(function(){
      console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
// ----------------------------------------

  // SELECT DATA
      $http.get('http://www.gvasample.esy.es/PDM-GVA%20ADMIN_2/getdata.php?id='+studentnumber).then(function (data){

      if(studentnumber == data.data.id && username == data.data.username){
          $rootScope.userInfo = data.data;

          $ionicLoading.hide();
           $state.go('app.studhome');
      }
      else{
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        alert("error");
      }
      });



/* MODAL
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  ---------------
*/



/* INSERT
    $http.get('http://localhost/grade/insertdata.php?id='+studentnumber+'&name='+username).then(function (data){
        alert("data save successfully!");
    });
  */
  }
})

.controller('StudHomeCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.userInfo = $rootScope.userInfo;

  angular.module('demo', ['ngIdle'])
  // omitted for brevity
  .config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
    IdleProvider.idle(1*60); // 10 minutes idle
    IdleProvider.timeout(30); // after 30 seconds idle, time the user out
    KeepaliveProvider.interval(5*60); // 5 minute keep-alive ping
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
          // end their session and redirect to login
      });
  });


})

.controller('ParentHomeCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('ViewGradesCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('AdvisingCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('CurriculumCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('HistoryCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('ViewSchedulesCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('OfficialsCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('MarilaoHymnCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('SubjectEnrolledCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('RankingCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('AcademicDelinquencyCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('LogoutCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.logout = function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template:'Logging out....'});
    $localstorage.set('loggin_state', '');

    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
        $state.go('login');
        }, 30);

}; 
})
```

Your help will be well appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569051/ionic-how-to-show-different-menu-for-different-view

Comment: No sir because I have an existing menu already.
I used ionic start myApp sidemenu.
I used that code already and I encountered some problems like nothing will display on any page.
I think that code is used in creating menu file without an existing one.

Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

When people log in as either "student" or "parent" you could implement a factory to set their user state globally:

```
factory('userStateFactory', function(){
var myState ='';
return {
 setUserState : function(state) { myState = state },
 getUserState : function()      {return myState}
}
})
```

Then simply add it to your login Controller and set it respectively. Then in your Menu Controller, simply add ng-if expressions to list items. For instance:

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-if="{userStateFactory.getUserState() == 'student'}">
      <div class="sub">
        <a href="#/app/viewschedules" class="icon ion-pin">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SCHEDULES
        </a>
      </div>
      </ion-item>
```

You can use this or something along those lines to achieve what you are looking for in Ionic. Possibly you also need to trigger $apply() after the login screen because afaik Ionic deconnects view from the watch cycle when they are not in active state, and on tablet for instance, where the sidemenu can be always visible on the side, there is no clear way when they will become active states again. So if you want your changes to show, simply use $apply which will trigger a $digest.

Comment: Thank you sir for the response.

If it is okay to you, I will tell you again when I encountered some problems in that code.

Thank you sir. :)